# Windows 7 rejecting UDP packets

Tags: windows-7, udp, raw-sockets

I'm writing a program that should simultaneously send and receive special RAW UDP packets. Almost all fields (except MAC-addresses) are filled by myself. And besides that I'm using some fake IP options like: `FE 04 01 00` (I've tried different), but the whole IP header is right. So here is an example packet

- MACs: `30 85 a9 1f b8 d6 00 25 22 62 22 07 08 00`
- IP header: `48 00 00 3e 03 d0 00 00 40 11 bb b7 c0 a8 89 a1 c0 a8 89 01`

  - IP options:

    - `fd 04 01 00`
    - `fe 08 01 11 1d 15 0a 00`
- UDP header, payload: `c3 50 c3 55 00 1e d7 ce 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 11 22 33 44 55 66 77`

---

### Issue

**Precondition: windows firewall is disabled and no other firewall is running. On Windows 7 host program is launched with "Run as Administrator".
On Windows XP user is Administrator.**

When packet is sent to remote host with Windows XP (LAN), or to the localhost on Windows 7 or Windows XP then it's successfully received(on the remote host or localhost). But if the packet is sent to the remote host with Windows 7 (LAN) then it's rejected by the remote host with ICMP message "Parameter problem". This only can be seen using (for example) Wireshark: sample [wireshark capture file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7a7cq3p578paem/packets.pcapng)

Here's some source code on **sending**

```
ressrc = ResolveAddress(srcAddrStr, srcPort, addressFamily, socketType, protocol);
if (ressrc == NULL) {
  // handling
}

resdest = ResolveAddress(dstAddrStr, dstPort, ressrc->ai_family, ressrc->ai_socktype, ressrc->ai_protocol);
if (resdest == NULL)  {
  // handling
}

sendSock = socket(ressrc->ai_family, socketType, ressrc->ai_protocol);
if (sendSock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
  // handling
}

int optval = 1;
rc = setsockopt(sendSock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, (char *)&optval, sizeof(optval));
if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR) {
  // handling
}

// packetizing
WSABUF *wbuf = ...

rc = sendto(sendSock, wbuf[0].buf, wbuf[0].len, 0, resdest->ai_addr, resdest->ai_addrlen);
```

and **receiving**

```
ressrc = ResolveAddress(srcAddrStr, NULL, addressFamily, socketType, protocol);
if (ressrc == NULL) {
    //handling
}

recvSock = socket(ressrc->ai_family, socketType, ressrc->ai_protocol);
if (recvSock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    //handling
}

rc = bind(recvSock, ressrc->ai_addr, ressrc->ai_addrlen);
if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    //handling
}

while (1)
{
    fromlen = sizeof(safrom);
    rc = recvfrom(recvSock, buf, MAX_PACKET, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&safrom, &fromlen);
    if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        //handling
    }

    /*
     * handling received packet
     */
}
```

I've tried:

- comparing packets received on different hosts (no differences)
- putting receiving socket in promiscuous mode using `WSAIoctl` and `ioctlsocket` functions
- googling, but the only thing I've found about my issue is this [topic](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/24b0bba5-8056-4885-b63f-3445b16098e9/udp-behavior-issue-on-windows-server-2008?forum=winserverPN)

What can cause this problem? Should I turn something on/off? Or am I doing wrong something else?

Comment: My guess is that the Win7 network stack detects invalid packets no matter if the firewall is switched on or off. Other systems do the same.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I thought so too, but couldn't find anything related.
Do you have any suggestions on what could it be?

Comment: I solved this problem months ago by using WinPcap to receive packets. No idea whether it network stack of Win7 (@SteffenUllrich) or something else.